# C# - Overriding the return type from interface with a derived type using generics

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, generics, polymorphism

My goal is to have a dictionary which stores different Container objects that derive from a interface IContainer. The user can 
add different Container objects (as long as they implement IContainer) to this dictionary. The containers can add elements related to the 
container (eg configContainer will add configElements, diContainer will add diConfigElements).

The elements also implement from a interface. 
I want to avoid the scenario of DiConfigElements being added to ConfigContainer. I have looked at related questions and they dont quite solve my problem.
I feel that generics will solve my problem, I have a example but I get Argument 2: cannot convert from 'ConfigContainer' to 'IContainer'
I am using Unity C#.

test.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class test
{
    public Dictionary<string, IContainer<IResolveableItem>> containers;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        containers = new Dictionary<string, IContainer<IResolveableItem>>();
        ConfigContainer configContainer = new ConfigContainer();
        ConfigContainerElement configElement = new ConfigContainerElement();
        configElement.Name = "configTest";
        configElement.Path = "configTest/configTest";
        configContainer.Add("test1", configElement);

        containers.Add("config",configContainer);
    }
}
```

IContainer.cs

```
using System.Collections;

public interface IContainer<T> where T : IResolveableItem
{
    void Add(string key , T value);
}
```

ConfigContainer.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ConfigContainer : IContainer<ConfigContainerElement>
{
    public Dictionary<string, IResolveableItem> container = new Dictionary<string, IResolveableItem>();

    public void Add(string key, ConfigContainerElement value)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

ConfigContainerElement.cs

```
using System.Collections;

public class ConfigContainerElement : IResolveableItem
{
    protected string name;
    protected string path;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }

        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return path;
        }

        set
        {
            path = value;
        }
    }
}
```

IResolveableItem.cs

```
using System.Collections;

public interface IResolveableItem
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is the unity bits necessary for the question? If not, could you rewrite the code as an [mcve] and repost? Right now it's a bit of a jigsaw puzzle.

Comment: Also, you mention `IContainerAdd` in your question text but there's no code that declares or uses that interface, did you change the name of things before you posted the code? Did you actually mean `IContainer<IResolvableItem>`? If so then it's not so strange that the compiler complains, even if `T` implements `U`, `X<T>` does not implement `X<U>` or inherit from it.

Comment: There is nothing to more to strip down to be fair. The scriptableObject.CreateInstance is basically just a new instance of that type.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen i'll edit that bit now.

Comment: My point was that in order to compile it I have to copy/paste multiple bits of code, strip away some unnecessary things, an [mcve] should ideally just be 1 copy/paste and compile to reproduce your problem. Otherwise there's always the chance that I do something wrong and get a different error, or even worse, the same error just in a different place and/or for a different reason.

Comment: Basically, your container implements `IContainer<ConfigContainerElement>`, and though `ConfigContainerElement` implements `IResolvableItem`, your container does *not* implement `IContainer<IResolvableItem>`, so you cannot do it like this.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen try running that now.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen if thats the case how can I implement it so I can control what element can be passed in on specific containers?

Comment: You probably cannot do it, the point of generics is to enforce compile-time type safety, you apparently want your dictionary to allow any container that accepts any types, just as long as that container typed to just one type that implements IResolvableItem, you likely will have to do that using runtime checks and create your dictionary as `<string, object>` or similar. There are limitations to generics and you've just hit one of them.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yeah I thought of runtime checking, I guess I will have to use that instead of compile time type safety.

Comment: If you want a dictionary that only takes items of a specific type, `Dictionary<T>` does that. I'm likely oversimplifying or missing something. It might help if you explained why that isn't sufficient. I recommend trying really hard not to resort to runtime type checking.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is any type that implements Icontainer needs to be able to implement the add method. The type passed to the add method needs to implement Iresovableitem but be restricted to a certain type dictated by that container. E.g you can only pass configContainer.add(configElement) diConfigContainer.add(diConfigElement) and configElement and diConfigElement implement Iresovableitem.

Answer (score -1):

It's a limitation of generics, will have to use runtime checking.

Comment: Please flesh this out into a full answer explaining why and how to use run-time checking.